# Getting values from MultiSelect using Asp.net MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I've been banging my head against the wall for hours now, all examples I've come across on telerik's site only show how to populate the multiselect, but not how to get the selected values from it.

I need to know what to add to it on the view side, and what to add in the controller to access this data. Can anyone help?

this is the code for the MultiSelect component in my view.

```
@(Html.Kendo().MultiSelect()
                      .Name("Roller")
                      .Placeholder("Välj en eller flera roller.")
                      .DataValueField("Id")
                      .DataTextField("Name")
                      .AutoBind(false)
                      .DataSource(source => source.Read("GetAllRoles", "Members"))
                      .Value(Model.Roles)
                      )
```

Comment: Your creating a `<select>` with `name="Roller"` so it will bind to property `int[] Roller` (assuming the `Id` property if the datasource is `int`)

Comment: yes, Id is int. but how would I access it in the controller? I have two of these on the same page, would the ActionResult have both in the parameters?

Comment: You should be binding to a model with that property, but you could always use `public ActionResult XXX(int[] Roller)`

Comment: I tried that, Roller is null, currently my ActionResult looks like this: public ActionResult SaveMember(dbUser user, int[] Roller, int[] Tjänster), no annotation. would I need to add that?

Comment: And is your `@(Html.Kendo().MultiSelect()` code generating `<select name="Roller" ... >`? But I have just noticed your binding to `Model.Roles` so why are you not posting back your model (and using `.Name("Roles")`?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by <select name="Roller" ... >. I changed the name to Roles. but I don't know how to access stuff in the view from the controller. is an ActionLink the way to go, or do I need a input with the submit type to post stuff back?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112408/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-inifus).